# Tinymce not working in production admin (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, production

Tinymce in admin page is not working on production server. Can anyone help about this problem?
(It's properly working on my local server. Only get problems when I deploy to aws ec2)

-> The admin model
app/admin/about.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register About do
permit_params :content, :author, :title

form do |f|
f.inputs 'About' do
f.input :title
f.input :content, input_html: {class: "tinymce"}
f.input :author
end
f.actions
end
```

config/initializer/active_admin.rb

```
  config.register_javascript 'tinymce.js'
```

assets/javascripts/active_admin.js

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require tinymce
//= require tinymce-jquery

$(document).ready(function() {
  tinyMCE.init({
     mode: 'textareas',
   });
});
```

assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss

```
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

In production admin page, the input container has class="tinymce", but no text editor showing ( I guess css files are not loaded.)

Comment: Do you have errors in the browser console?

Comment: nope it's clean. The html source is showing like this <textarea rows="20" id="review_content" class="tinymce" name="review[content]"></textarea>

Comment: mode: 'textareas' or 'textarea' ?

Comment: What version of TinyMCE are you running? The 'mode' configuration option has been deprecated as of TinyMCE 4.x. If you are using TinyMCE 4+, you will need to configure a specific selector such as selector: "textarea", or  selector: ".tinymce"